# Make my "arrows" work on click event

Tags: jquery

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="navigation-arrows">
     <div class="left-arrow">
       <a href="#" class="navigation a-left">
         <span class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </a>
     </div>
     <div class="right-arrow">
       <a href="#" class="navigation a-right">
         <span class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       </a>
     </div>
   </div>
```

And JS is like:

```
$('a.navigation').on('click', function(e){
      console.log('click');
      if (e.className === 'navigation a-left')
        console.log('left');
      } else if (e.className === 'navigation a-right') {
       console.log('right');
      }
  });
```

I want my arrows be working by click. But I can't figure what is wrong. It works when I click, but without conditions. Only `console.log('click');` works. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your code is that you're attempting to read the `className` property from the `e` variable, which is the click event that was raised. Events do not have a `className` property. You could use `e.currentTarget.className` instead.

Alternatively you could use jQuery's `hasClass()` method. This would be much more reliable as it won't break should you ever re-order the classes on the element, or add/remove one. Try this:

```
$('a.navigation').on('click', function(e){
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.hasClass('a-left')) {
        console.log('left');
    } else if ($el.hasClass('a-right')) {
        console.log('right');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes in your code, Try this

```
$('a.navigation').on('click', function(){      
      if ($(this).attr('class') === 'navigation a-left'){
        console.log('left');
      } else if ($(this).attr('class')  === 'navigation a-right') {
       console.log('right');
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use `hasClass` :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.navigation').on('click', function(){
        alert('click');

        if ($(this).hasClass("navigation a-left"))
            alert('left');

        else if( $(this).hasClass("navigation a-right")) 
            alert('right');
    })
})
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="navigation-arrows">
            <div class="left-arrow">
                <a href="#" class="navigation a-left">
                    <span class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true">Left</span>
                </a>
            </div>
            
            <div class="right-arrow">
                <a href="#" class="navigation a-right">
                    <span class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true">Right</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('a.navigation').on('click', function(){
                alert('click');

                if ($(this).hasClass("navigation a-left"))
                    alert('left');

                else if( $(this).hasClass("navigation a-right")) 
                    alert('right');
            })
        })
         
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```